# In c++ using the ceil a division is not working?

Tags: c++, math, int

well i tried this
it don't work
with ceil in c++

```
int n, m, a;
double r1, r2;
cin >> n;
cin >> m;
cin >> a;
r1 = (n/a);
r2 = (m/a);
cout << (ceil(r1)*ceil(r2));
```

the n/a operation shall return a double in case of n = 3 and a =2 but it doesn't

also..

the m/a operation shall return a double in case of m = 3 and a =2 but it doesn't

Comment: `the n/a operation shall return a double` No it shall not. `n/a` performs an integer division: the result is an integer, truncated towards zero. So does `m/a`. Make it `r1 = double(n) / a;`

Answer (score 8):

Here is the problem,
`n/a` and `m/a` will evaluate to integers since n,m,a are integers and the integer will get stored  into double , to avoid this you can type cast like this

```
r1=(double)n/a;
r2=(double)n/a;
```

Or simply change the data type of a from int to double,
maybe (It will help you to #A. Theatre Square)

Answer (score 1):

Since `n`, `m`, and `a` are all of type `int`, `n/a` and `m/a` will also be integers, meaning 3/2 will be equal to 1. Changing `n` and `m` to type `double` should fix that problem.

Comment: Yes, changing to double will fix the problem but I can't do it. It is not allowed in the problem. Also even if both n and a are integers the division could be a double and since i am not storing it in an int variable it should not convert it into int right?

Comment: They will return an integer even if you store it as a double. If n and m have to be integers, you can always try casting it into a double. `r1 = double(n/a);`

Comment: I think it should be with no ()

Answer (score 0):

Changing any one of the variable's data types from 'int' to 'double' will work since the operations between two integers result in an integer.
If you cannot convert any one variable's data type, then I suggest going for the brute-force way of finding ceil.

```
function ceil(int a, int b){
    int d = a/b;
    if(a%b!=0) d++;
    return d;
}
```

[ Explicitly raise the count if 'a' is not a multiple of 'b']

Say two variables, 'a'=7, 'b'=3. d initially will be 2, then as 7 is not a multiple of 3, 'd' will be incremented, and we get the expected answer: d = 3.